# cassert not found error

Tags: c++, objective-c, box2d

I'm trying to use Box2D in my project, everything was working fine until I dragged across some older obj-c files, and then compiled and that the weird error appeared

> cassert not found

Obviously I googled this error and found a few [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049868/objective-c-importing-c-class-fails-cassert-not-found)

Mostly saying rename your files to .mm, but I don't want to use C++, I want to use my obj-c classes, and just access a C++ class to setup the box2d stuff, so what's the solution in that situation? or am I going to be forced to code the whole game in C++?

Comment: you can't include c++ header in .m files directly or indirectly. which basically means you can't include c++ header in ObjC header without rename .m to .mm

Comment: Renaming files to .mm does not force you to code anything in C++.